# How implement Flutter login authentication & registration using Http post

Tags: flutter, http, dart, dio

How users got to know login Successful or Login Unsuccessful?
when the user put the correct LoginId & Password, which is in my API, then only it should show a snack bar that the login is successful otherwise user is not found.

my login_model.dart

```
    class LoginResponseModel {
  final String token;
  final String error;

  LoginResponseModel({this.token, this.error});

  factory LoginResponseModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return LoginResponseModel(
      token: json["token"] != null ? json["token"] : "",
      error: json["error"] != null ? json["error"] : "",
    );
  }
}

class LoginRequestModel {
  // String email;
  // String password;
  String LoginId;
  String Password;

  LoginRequestModel({
    this.LoginId,
    this.Password,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    Map<String, dynamic> map = {
      'LoginId': LoginId.trim(),
      'Password': Password.trim(),
    };

    return map;
  }
}



 TextFormField(
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                      onSaved: (input) =>
                          loginRequestModel.LoginId = input!,//=============================================================LoginId
```

Comment: Can you give more details please? We do not follow that tutorial and we did not watch over your shoulder as you followed it. What did you do? What happened? What did you expect to happen instead?

Comment: hey, can you please check now, I added my model class and My API service.

Answer (score 1):

Your `url` variable starts with an empty space. That is no allowed. Fix it.

Comment: The error is gone, but I didn't see the message `login Successful ` or Login Unsuccessful  if the user put wrong info which is not in my API

Comment: You have not posted any code that would show those messages. Maybe you can debug yourself and if you cannot find your problem, ask a new question with the code that is relevant?

Comment: Debug successful and it's showing the snack bar, but it's always displaying Unsuccessful login. I Edit & add the code where I'm Check user data with API data can you please check it.